# Why isn't my ng-repeat updating?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to angular. This is my first foray into it.

I have a very basic app that repeats through some rows, which is filtered. When I push new data into my object it does not appear in my table even though I expect it to.

Any ideas?

```
UonApp.controller('CtrlFees', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.student = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    $scope.currencySymbol = '£';


    $scope.addFee = function() {
        $scope.fees.push = { id: 4, studentId: parseInt($scope.student), paymentAmount: $scope.newAmount, paymentDate: '2015-05-19' }
        $scope.newAmount = '';

        console.table($scope.fees);
    }

    $scope.fees = [
        { id: 1, studentId: 3, paymentAmount: 9000, paymentDate: '2014-06-03' },
        { id: 2, studentId: 2, paymentAmount: 9000, paymentDate: '2014-03-08' },
        { id: 3, studentId: 2, paymentAmount: 9000, paymentDate: '2014-05-04' }
    ];

    console.table($scope.fees);

}]);
```

And my View:

```
<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Payment Amount</th>
                            <th class="right">Payment Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="fee in filteredFees = (fees | orderBy: 'paymentDate' | filter:{studentId:student})">
                            <td>{{fee.paymentDate | date:'mediumDate'}}</td>
                            <td class="right">{{fee.paymentAmount | currency:currencySymbol}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="right">Add Fee Payment</th>
                            <td class="right"><input type="number" placeholder="Amount" ng-model="newAmount"> <input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addFee()"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="right">Total</th>
                            <td class="right strong"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

I also need to sum the payments amounts listed, including the added row.

Comment: Did you mean to do `$scope.fees.push({id: 4... });`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in `$scope.addFee`

```
$scope.fees.push = { id: 4, studentId: parseInt($scope.student), paymentAmount: $scope.newAmount, paymentDate: '2015-05-19' }
```

You probably mean `$scope.fees.push(...)`

Comment: Yes! That's it. Such a quick answer, I can't accept it for another 8 minutes. Now I just need to sum the column and I can get some sleep.